# Accessing class tree from its field's tree

Tags: scala, scala-macro-paradise

I'd like to write a macro which enriches case classes. When I declare my case class like this:

`case class User(int id, @tagged name)`

I want to be able to inject some stuff into the `Tree` of this class having only annottees. So far I was only able to reach the `Symbol` of the enclosing class, but looks like it's not enough (see Eugene's answer [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/14addbb014/scala-reflection-classdef-parents)). I also don't want to use deprecated api of `c.enclosingClass`.
Is there any way to reach parent `ClassDef` in paradise 2.1.0 (Scala 2.11)?